# Rock a Hawk - a Phrase from a Movie

Tags: american-english

Must be one of those phrases that everyone knows but nobody explains. Encountered it in this sentence: "My girlfriend thinks I'm too old **to rock a hawk**." (from the movie called Wheelman)
Could anyone explain to me what this means?

Comment: He’s too old to cut his hair into a mohawk. That’s for the young, cool kids. Or so his GF claims.

Comment: The sense of the verb “rock” here is: to wear a particular style of clothing, etc. and look good or fashionable.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Since this question was answered in a comment, it is still marked as "unanswered."

Comment: I really wish that someone would replace the "Add a comment" link on stack exchange with text similar to "Ask a clarifying question". If you know the answer, do not write the answer as a comment. Some questions on the website cannot be answered without asking for clarification. That is why the comment section exists.

Comment: There are a lot of Google hits for _"rock a hawk" + meaning_. It soon becomes clear that _hawk_ is short for _mohawk_, the hair style.

Comment: @SamuelMuldoon You do understand why people  post answers as comments though right? It’s because we get sick of being downvoted for trivial reasons after exerting the effort to answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

The following two sentences are equivalent in meaning:

> - "My girlfriend thinks I'm too old to rock a hawk."
> - "My girlfriend thinks I'm too old to wear a Mohawk."

In this context, you can substitute the verb "**wear**" for the verb "**rock**"
You can also substitute "**hawk**" for "**mohawk**"

I suppose that another suitable replacement for the verb "**rock**" might be "**sport**"

> "My girlfriend thinks I'm too old to be ***sporting** a Mohawk-style haircut."

Lastly, consider the following:

> My girlfriend thinks I'm too old to have my hair cut so that the hair down the center of my head is longer than the hair on the sides.

Comment: Isn't this just a rehash of Dan Bron's comment? :)

Comment: @user405662 Yes, but this is answer, not a comment. It would be improved by referencing a dictionary for *rock=wear* at least.

Comment: +1 for posting the correct answer as an answer. I note as a minor and tangential point that, for clarity, the written form of the phrase might be rendered as "rock a 'hawk"—to signal to readers that _'hawk_ is an abbreviated form of a longer word.

Comment: @user405662 Yes, this answer is just a rehash of Dan Bron's comment. Answers to questions are supposed to be posted as answers, not comments. The comment section is where you ask questions about the question. If a question cannot be answered without additional clarification, then you post a comment. I wish that the powers that be would replace the text on the "add a comment" link with the text "ask for clarification"

Comment: @Samuel Muldoon: Thank you! Got it. :)

Comment: @user405662 Dan Bron is an experienced user of EL&U, and likely left a comment rather than an answer in the belief that this question would be closed as substandard (it fails to demonstrate any attempt at initial research) but that a comment might be helpful. Neither he nor other experienced EL&U users will take offense if we leave a comment that is expanded into a full answer, and indeed sometimes we explicitly do so because we do not have the time to provide a full answer.

Answer (score 2):

Hawk = [Mohawk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQUDb.jpg)

Rock = Wear (E.g. I'm going to rock my new shoes this weekend). Usually for something that's nice.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I suspect that the downvote may be related to the fact that the hyperlink embedded in your answer doesn't work (at least it doesn't for me).

Comment: Fixed and added Wikipedia link to the Native American tribe.